# Parameterizing a Gaussian distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, markov-process, gaussian-process, parameterization, diffusion

I am reading this [blog post](https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2021-07-11-diffusion-models/#speed-up-diffusion-model-sampling) where the author talks about diffusion models. Let's keep diffusion out of the conversation for now. The author showcased that we can parameterize a Gaussian distribution by a desired standard deviation sigma as shown below:

[image]

I didn't get how the sigma value is inserted here. Can someone please elaborate this in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume an AR(1) model: for $t\ge 1$
$$x_t=\sqrt{\alpha}x_{t-1}+\sqrt{1-\alpha}\epsilon_t\qquad\epsilon_t\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$$
Then, for $0<\sigma^2<1-\alpha$,
$$\sqrt{1-\alpha}\epsilon_t\quad\text{and}\quad\sqrt{1-\alpha-\sigma^2}\epsilon_t^1+\sigma\epsilon_t^2$$
have the same distribution when $\epsilon_t,\epsilon_t^1,\epsilon_t^2$ are iid $\mathcal N(0,1)$.

I am however puzzled by the decomposition proposed in the [reproduced entry](https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2021-07-11-diffusion-models/#speed-up-diffusion-model-sampling):
$$x_{t-1}=\sqrt{\alpha_{t-1}}x_{0}+\underbrace{\sqrt{1-\alpha_{t-1}-\sigma^2_t}\epsilon_t+\sigma_t\epsilon}_{\displaystyle\sqrt{1-\alpha_{t-1}}\epsilon_{t-1}}\qquad\epsilon,\epsilon_t\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$$
because this turns $\epsilon_t$ and $\epsilon_{t-1}$ into correlated Normal variates, contrary to the initial assumption.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you elaborate a bit more on the  0<2<1−
IID part? I got the idea but if you can expand it with a small proof, that will clarify everything

Comment: The sum of two independent Normal variate is another Normal variate.

Comment: Oh yes!. Thanks a lot